# Nouns that describe actions but are not verb nouns

Tags: nouns, semantics

So I had a little semantics argument about English verbs, where the other side claimed, let me quote:

> They are one in the same, every action is a verb, every verb is an action.

I disagree, but not being a native English speaker, unlike my opponent, I'm having problems catching up. I could disprove the second part easily using verbs "like", "have" and "want".

But as of the first part, an action that is not a verb... I know one: `action` It's an *action* actually, because you "Take action." But is there anything else?

Comment: I didn't edit your quotation, because I didn't know if I should add [sic] or change "in" to "and". See http://grammarist.com/usage/one-in-the-same/

Comment: This is the way author posted it and I have no idea what is the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

The Original Poster's friend is suffering from what is known as *TEACHER INDUCED ERROR*. People have this view because, unfortunately teachers at school have the habit of telling students that *verbs denote actions, nouns denote things, adjectives describe nouns, adverbs describe adjectives* and so on and so forth.

There are literally thousands of nouns that denote actions. Here are a few:

- dismissal
- massacre
- baptism
- release
- edification
- pugilism
- launch

Not only are there thousand of such words, but English is fully equipped with grammatical devices for showing the thematic roles in relation to such actions. So we can show, for examples, both the actors and patients in relation to such actions:

- The dismissal of the managing director by the board
- The massacre of the Enterprise crew by the Romulans
- The baptism of Jesus by John the Baptist
- The release of the prisoners by the authorities
- The launch of the advertising campaign by the creative agency

Comment: Massacre of the Enterprise crew by the ... **Daleks** ?!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, I know, couldn't remember any names! Perhaps you could suggest one!

Comment: How about the Romulans? Or the Dominion? (But we all know the Enterprise crew was never massacred, so it may not actually matter)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Done ...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that some verb are not actions: you listed states of being. "A verb . . . conveys an action . . ., an occurrence (happen, become), or a state of being." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb)

In my humble opinion, English is an excellent language, in part, because of the flexibility of the words. Colloquially, what you are looking for is **nouning a verb**. ([Short explanation](https://oilpatchwriting.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/gerunds-nouning-a-verb/).) The technical term is "[gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)", which makes me think of farming not grammar, but I am a little strange.

Comment: It goes deeper than this. The noun _motion_ for instance references ... er, motion, and the verb _seem_, for instance, references appearance. Eventually, notional ideas of even these most major of word classes have to be at least greatly augmented by analysis involving syntactical behaviour.

Comment: Nouning a verb is something that didn't help me, since every verb can be nouned it's pretty much invalid. Also all non-verbs like login, logoff and workout are made from words that are implicitly verbs not nouns.